# Зачем в Visual C# свойство Margin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Зачем в `Visual C#` (использую `Visual Studio 2017`) у элементов управления свойство `margin` если вне зависимости от его значения можно свободно перемещать элементы управления и распологать их рядом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чтобы при масштабировании окна с пришпиленными контролами, они не заезжали друг на друга в процесс изменения положения и размеров.